# I developed a discode bot that randomly assigns a role, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I was randomly trying to create a discord bot that assigns me a dormitory for Harry Potter when I was in which a bug occurred. No matter how hard I tried to fix it, it couldn't be fixed. The version of discord.py is 1.3.2, and Python 3.8 is currently in use. How can I fix the bug?

Error

> discord.ext.commands.errors.missingrequiredargument: ctx is a required argument that is missing.

CODE

```py
app.py
...

@client.command(pass_context=True, name="add")
async def enter(self, ctx):
    await ctx.send("Wait..")
    await asyncio.sleep(3.0)
    num = r.randint(1, 4)

    if num == 1:
        #Gryffindor
        egg = r.randint(1, 2)
        if egg == 1:
            await ctx.send("Um... it's hard... It's very difficult...")        
            await asyncio.sleep(2.0)
            await ctx.send("No Slytherin? Really?")
            await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
            await ctx.send("So, I can't help it.")
            await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
        else:
            await ctx.send("Hmm...")
            await ctx.send("Slytherin shouldn't go.")

        await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="「」Gryffindor")
        user = ctx.message.author
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send("Gryffindor!")

    if num == 2:
        # Slytherin
        await ctx.send("There's nothing to see!")
        await asyncio.sleep(0.5)
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="「」Slytherin")
        user = ctx.message.author
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send("Slytherin!")

    if num == 3:
        # Hufflepuff
        await ctx.send("Hmm...")
        await asyncio.sleep(1.4)
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="「」Hufflepuff")
        user = ctx.message.author
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send("Hufflepuff!")

    if num == 4:
        #Lebenclaw
        await ctx.send("Well, it would be hard for difficult ...")
        await asyncio.sleep(1.2)
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="「」Lebenclaw")
        user = ctx.message.author
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send("Lebenclaw!")
```

Comment: Are you using the bot extension or just a simple discord.Client? Your code snippet here doesn't include your startup code meaning we can't tell.

Comment: Bot = Declared discord.Client(), I don't think this is a problem.
(```bot = discord.Client()```)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
bot = discord.Client()
```

This is exactly your problem.
What you are currently using by
`@client.command(pass_context=True, name="add")`

is the discord.ext.commands library, meaning you are using add-on to discord.py (but which is included in your installation). Here is its documentation: [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html)

How do we fix this?
It's quite easy:
Instead of 
`client = discord.Client()`
Do the following: (This code is taken from the official example: [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html)

```py
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
```

Always include your whole code in questions, or atleast a minimally reproducible example.

Edit:
It also seems like you are using an old code snippet, you do not need to use `pass_context` anymore.